# When people say "think tall thoughts"

Tags: meaning, expressions, slang, phrase-meaning, colloquialisms

During small talk I heard someone say,

> **Think tall thoughts**. That might help.

when another person was complaining about being short-heighted.

I checked online information, but I still need some clarification here.

Does this phrase mean:

(1) Just imagine you are tall and you will be more confident?

(2) Try to think from tall people's perspective and you will find the disadvantages of being tall?

(3) Imagine you are tall and you might grow taller? (Most online examples seem to have this meaning, but the hearer is an adult. I doubt that could help.)

(4) figurative or humorous use: Try to look on the bright side or think about being successful?

(5) Anything else?

Comment: The only place on the Internet I can find this is on the Facebook page of a corgi (a small dog) "Jasper Islington". "Think tall thoughts" is simply humour - it is an ironic suggestion intended to be helpful. It is equivalent to saying "Imagine that you are tall." (Which, of course, does not help at all...)

Comment: It's not an American idiom. It's just a play on words.

Comment: It’s a humorous use alluding to 3.